# Why is the program NOT stuck in an infinite loop?

Tags: c, algorithm, loops, cs50, greedy

Noob question here.
I've just started to learn programming, and I've taken the cs50 course. I've done the first 3 problems from the problem set 1 in C, but I don't understand why in my 3rd program, there is a loop that should cause the program to get stuck, but it doesn't, and it works as intended. The last else if statement shouldn't cause the program to get stuck in a loop? If for example we reach the last loop with a value of 4. So change(4) - nickel(5) would result to -1, which is lower than 0, making the condition true, why doesn't the program get stuck in this last loop, and keep on substracting the value of nickel and increasing the count of pennys?

```
int main()
{
    int change, count_p = 0, count_n = 0, count_d = 0, count_q = 0;
    const int penny = 1;
    const int nickel = 5;
    const int dime = 10;
    const int quarter = 25;

    do
    {
        change = get_int("Enter amount of change: ");
    }
    while (change < 0);

    while (change > 0)
    {
        if (change - quarter >= 0)
        {
            change -= quarter;
            count_q += 1;
        }
        else if ((change - quarter < 0) && (change - dime >= 0))
        {
            change -= dime;
            count_d += 1;
        }
        else if ((change - dime < 0) && (change - nickel >= 0))
        {
            change -= nickel;
            count_n += 1;
        }
        else if (change - nickel < 0)
        {
            change -= penny;
            count_p += 1;
        }
    }
    // int count_tot = count_q + count_d + count_n + count_p;
    // printf("This is the total amount of coins: %i\n", count_tot);
    printf("This is number of quarters: %i\n", count_q);
    printf("This is number of dimes: %i\n", count_d);
    printf("This is number of nickels: %i\n", count_n);
    printf("This is number of pennys: %i\n", count_p);
}
```

Comment: change(4) - nickel(5) is -1, but in the conditional body, penny(1) is subtracted from change(4), leaving it with 3, 2, 1 and finally 0.

Comment: All of the `< 0` tests could just be removed. The last `else if` could just be `else`.

Comment: As a side note: you can leave out parts of the conditional like `(change - quarter < 0) &&`, because you already ruled that out with the preceding cases

Comment: Just print out the value of `change` at the end of each iteration: do you still have a question then?

Comment: Computung `change - nickel` does not, itself, modify the value of either `change` or `nickel`.

Comment: Overall, I think we're all guessing at the specific flaw in your analysis that leads you to conclude that the loop should not terminate. Perhaps you have confused yourself by expressing more complicated conditions than are necessary, as a previous comment observed.  You should satisfy yourself that no matter what the value of `change` is when the body of the loop is entered, exactly one of the conditional alternatives within is executed, and each of those reduces `change`.  As a result, `change` must eventually fall to zero (or below), whatever its initial value.

Comment: Side note: In week 2 of CS50, you will learn how to use a debugger called `debug50`, which will allow you to run your program line by line while monitoring the values of all variables. That way, you can easily see what is happening inside your program.

Comment: Sidenote: You don't need a loop to calculate the change. `count_q = change / quarter;` `change -= count_q * quarter;` `count_d = change / dime;` `change -= count_d * dime;` `count_n = change / nickel;` `change -= count_n * nickel;` `count_p = change;` would do.

Comment: @TedLyngmo using modulo would be even better. `count_q = change / quarter; change %= quarter;`

Comment: `change - quarter >= 0` seems like a cumbersome way to write `change >= quarter`

Comment: @Chris I'm not sure about better, but it's less typing, that's for sure :-)

Answer (score 1):

I can't see anything that would cause an infinite loop. Your last condition will always be true if the preceding conditions were false.

But you can clean up your conditions:

```
int main() {
    int change, count_p = 0, count_n = 0, count_d = 0, count_q = 0;
    const int penny = 1;
    const int nickel = 5;
    const int dime = 10;
    const int quarter = 25;

    do {
        change = get_int("Enter amount of change: ");
    } while (change < 0);

    while (change > 0) {
        if (change >= quarter) {
            change -= quarter;
            count_q += 1;
        }
        else if (change >= dime) {
            change -= dime;
            count_d += 1;
        }
        else if (change >= nickel) {
            change -= nickel;
            count_n += 1;
        }
        else {
            change -= penny;
            count_p += 1;
        }
    }

    printf("This is number of quarters: %i\n", count_q);
    printf("This is number of dimes: %i\n", count_d);
    printf("This is number of nickels: %i\n", count_n);
    printf("This is number of pennys: %i\n", count_p);
}
```

Secondly, since repeated subtraction is really just division and then we want to test the remainder of the change...

```
int main() {
    int change, count_p = 0, count_n = 0, count_d = 0, count_q = 0;
    const int penny = 1;
    const int nickel = 5;
    const int dime = 10;
    const int quarter = 25;

    do {
        change = get_int("Enter amount of change: ");
    } while (change < 0);

    count_q = change / quarter;
    change %= quarter;
    count_d = change / dime;
    change %= dime;
    count_n = change / nickel;
    change %= nickel;
    count_p = change;

    printf("This is number of quarters: %i\n", count_q);
    printf("This is number of dimes: %i\n", count_d);
    printf("This is number of nickels: %i\n", count_n);
    printf("This is number of pennys: %i\n", count_p);
}
```

Comment: Ah, I see now that I've misunderstood how the variable itself is affected by the loop, and how the program actually behaves.Thank you guys for your answers, it's clear now.And thanks as well for the helpfull tips, like a better version of the code, and the debugger called debug50.

Answer (score 1):

In every condition you have something like `change -= something`. This means that on every loop `change` decreases stricly. The while loop condition is `change>0`, thus at some time either `change==0` or `change<0` and this will break the loop.